# Laravel dependency injection does not find the class

Tags: php, dependency-injection, phpunit, laravel-5.3

I'm using PHPUnit to test my application, in this case I'm testing an API call (I'm doing GET, POST, PUT and DELETE through it). index method responds to GET(/api) route, in this method I have a custom Request:

```
public function index(\Api\User\Requests\IndexRequest $request)
{
    // do some stuff...
}
```

Api\User\Requests\IndexRequest class looks like this:

```
class Request extends IndexApiRequest
{
    // some methods in here
}
```

When I execute the test via PHPUnit it prompts:

```
Class Api\User\Requests\IndexRequest does not exist
```

Checking the trace route it dies in Illuminate\Routing\RouteDependencyResolverTrait. I couldn't figure out how I can interfere in the execution since it seems to happen between PHPUnit and Laravel.

Does anyone have an idea? I'm using Laravel 5.3, PHPUnit 5.6.5 running on Ubuntu 16.04, PHP 7.0 and nginx.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `class Request extends IndexApiRequest` to `class IndexRequest extends IndexApiRequest`